# Figuring out most recent Anniversary Date

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I'm writing a Training DB.

Students have a ServiceDate (the day they started working at the company).

I need to find out if they have taken a given course in the last year from their ServiceDate.  Not calendar year, the need to take certain classes resets on the Anniversary date...so the due dates vary with each student.

I'm thinking I can do something like this...but I'm sure that there's a much easier way to do it:

```
iDiff = cint((Date() - ServiceDate)/365) 'Gives the number of years between the ServiceDate and today
dMostRecent = DateAdd("yyyy",iDiff, ServiceDate) 'Uses the mm/dd from ServiceDate, but makes it the current year
If dMostRecent > Date() then 'If the new date is in the future...
  dMostRecent = DateAdd("yyyy",-1,dMostRecent) 'Subtract 1 year
End If
'dMostRecent should now be within the last 12 months and I can check the dates that the given course was last taken and compare
```

Is there an easier way to do this...or does anyone see problems with this method?  Working with dates can be a pain sometimes...

Comment: Leapyears have more than 365 days

Comment: Very true, but it is only a 1 day difference, and would be a fraction of a year.  I don't think that would matter much...but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but I suspect `DateSerial` could be useful.

```vb
Public Function LastAnniversaryDate(ByVal pServiceDate As Date) As Date
    Dim dteThisYear As Date
    Dim dteReturn As Date
    dteThisYear = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(pServiceDate), Day(pServiceDate))
    If dteThisYear > Date Then
        dteReturn = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, dteThisYear)
    Else
        dteReturn = dteThisYear
    End If
    LastAnniversaryDate = dteReturn
End Function
```

Leap years was mentioned as a possible complication.  `DateSerial` can cope as you may wish.  For example, since 2015 is not a leap year, `DateSerial(2015, 2, 29)` returns *3/1/2015*.  That means that `LastAnniversaryDate(#2/29/2012#)` will give you *3/1/2015*.

If you want Feb 28 as the anniversary date for a Feb 29 service date, you'll need to revise this function.

Comment: `dServiceDate = DLookup("ServiceDate", "tblUserList", "NTID='" & sNTID & "'")        
  dReturn = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(dServiceDate), Day(dServiceDate))      
  If dReturn > Date Then dReturn = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, dReturn)`
I shortened to this (only 3 lines)...nice and compact.  Tested it against multiple dates, leap years and not.  My original code, leap years were only a problem right at that point..end of Feb, start of March.  This seems to work better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This method might be slightly more accurate. Not sure if it's quicker or not, but it should help avoid your leap year issues. (unless the original service date was a leap year.. then you will have to add or subtract a day.)

```
If (DatePart("m", ServiceDate) = 2 And DatePart("d", ServiceDate) = 29) Then
  ServiceDate = DateAdd("d", -1, ServiceDate)
End If   

dMostRecent = DatePart("m", ServiceDate) & "-" & DatePart("m", ServiceDate) & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)

If dMostRecent > Date Then
    dMostRecent = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, dMostRecent)
End If
```